# Get stderror and stdout of command within c++

Tags: c++, command, popen

I am trying to execute a command within C++ and get the stdout and stderror of that command separately.

I have tried used popen() however since it only captures stdout, I have had to redirect stderr to stdout. Is there a way to get stdout and stderr separately on Linux?

So far I have been using:

```
std::string runCommand(const char * command) {
        std::array<char, 128> buffer;
        std::string ret;

        FILE* pipe = popen(std::string(command).append(" 2>&1").c_str(), "r");
        while (fgets(buffer.data(), 128, pipe) != NULL)
                ret += buffer.data();
        pclose(pipe);

        return ret;
}
```

Am I on the right track? Should I continue to use popen or would the pipe/fork/exec method be better for this sort of problem?

Comment: The big question of course is "is it ok to have *both combined in one, with stdout strangely buffered"*

Comment: Look into Boost.Process. example: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.io